# Laravel $e->getMessage empty on Request validation error

Tags: php, validation, laravel, request

I'm trying to setup custom error handlers in Handler.php but when I try to get the error message when a Request validation isn't met I get an empty response.

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    dd($e->getMessage());
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

My rules are set to:

```
'min:10'
```

So when I don't provide parameters of length 10 I want it to output that error within $e->getMessage() so I can do whatever I want to do with it, but the error is always empty. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide your controller method code where your validation rules are?

Answer (score 2):

`Exception` will not give you errors that occurs for `Validator`.

`Validator` error are sent on its object and by `errors()` method. So, after calling the errors method on a Validator instance, you will receive an `Illuminate\Support\MessageBag` instance, which has a variety of convenient methods for working with error messages.

For more details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-error-messages